# Use blank line as end for one region and as start of another

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I want to syntax highlight a header region in custom style and a body region with the existing markdown style:

```
Title: Test Note
Id: 147648d8-8680-4847-8f50-dd4a67f870b5
Created-At: 2018-02-26 22:44:20.784550+00:00
Updated-At: 2018-02-26 22:44:20.784550+00:00

# A heading
Some text
```

The common start and end of the regions `Header` and `markdownBody` is the blank line. I tried this:

```
syn match HeaderValue contained '.*$'
syn match HeaderKey contained '^.*:' nextgroup=HeaderValue

syn region Header start="\%^" end="\ze\n\n" transparent contains=HeaderKey

unlet! b:current_syntax
syn include @MARKDOWN syntax/markdown.vim
let b:current_syntax = "mystyle"

syn region MarkdownBody start="\n\n" end="\%$" contains=@MARKDOWN

hi def link HeaderKey Type
hi def link HeaderValue Comment
```

This works for the header, but not for the body. If I replace the two occurrences of `\n\n` with, e. g., `END` and replace the blank line in the text with `END`, it works, though.

This seems to mean there is a special handling of `\n\n`. How can I use a blank line as a `start` and `end` marker?

Comment: Thanks to you question, I managed to resolve a similar problem, where I have root region that contains two regions that shares the same element as separator (ie, pascal like function definition where the funtion private vars declaration block and the function body)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution: differently from what I assumed, `syn region` works line-oriented already, so a single `\n` instead of `\n\n` does it. Take a look at [the working code](https://github.com/fqxp/nete-vim/blob/master/syntax/nete.vim) if you’re interested.